# How to convert an object containing 3 numbers into three separate columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, type-conversion, multiple-columns

I ran a sentiment analysis model on my dataset of tweets and created a new column with the output called 'scores'. The output was a set of 3 probabilities: the first indicates the probability that the tweet is negative, the second indicates the probability that the tweet is neutral, the third indicates the probability that the tweet is positive.
For example:

```
[0.013780469, 0.94494355, 0.041276094]
```

[Here is a screenshot of a few observations of the 'score' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7u7b.png)

Using this code: `df.scores.dtype` I found the data type to be an object.

I want to create three separate columns, 'Negative', 'Neutral', "Positive' for each probability. Therefore, I would like to separate the 'scores'. How might I go about doing this?

I already tried this:

```
df[['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']] = pd.DataFrame(df.scores.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

But I got an error saying:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I also tried this:

```
df[['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('~') for x in df['scores'].tolist() ])
```

But I got an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When using `str(x).split()` instead of `x.split()`, I got this error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Here is the output when I do `print(df['scores'])` :

```
0       [0.07552529 0.7626313  0.16184345]
1       [0.0552146  0.7753107  0.16947475]
2       [0.06891786 0.6625086  0.26857358]
3       [0.10522033 0.7078265  0.18695314]
4       [0.04945428 0.78878057 0.16176508]
                       ...                
4976    [0.0196455  0.9556966  0.02465796]
4977    [0.02270025 0.94873595 0.02856365]
4978    [0.01378047 0.94494355 0.04127609]
4979    [0.05239033 0.9061995  0.04141007]
4980    [0.0651902  0.9061197  0.02869013]
Name: scores, Length: 4981, dtype: object
```

Here is the output when I do `df.loc[0:5, "scores"].to_dict()`:

```
{0: '[0.07552529 0.7626313  0.16184345]',
 1: '[0.0552146  0.7753107  0.16947475]',
 2: '[0.06891786 0.6625086  0.26857358]',
 3: '[0.10522033 0.7078265  0.18695314]',
 4: '[0.04945428 0.78878057 0.16176508]',
 5: '[0.02224329 0.87228    0.10547666]'}
```

Comment: Your first expression should work. My guess is that `scores` is actually a string. You can convert its content to lists by applying `ast.literal_eval`. Please provide a df constructor so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tranbi Sorry, what is a df constructor?

Comment: You could give us the output (limited to a minimal reproducible example) of `df.to_dict()` for instance.

Comment: @Tranbi how can I apply `ast.literal_eval` to a df column? (Thanks so much for your help)

Comment: Please post the output of `df.loc[0:5, "scores"].to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Create some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["scores"], data=["[0.013780469, 0.94494355, 0.041276094]",
                                            "[0.013780469, 0.94494355, 0.941276094]",
                                            "[0.513780469, 0.74494355, 0.041276094]",
                                            "[0.813780469, 0.14494355, 0.541276094]"])
# First strip the unwanted characters and split by ", "
df[['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']] = df.scores.str.replace("[", "", regex=True).replace("]", "", regex=True).str.split(", ", expand=True)

# Drop the original scores column
df.drop("scores", axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

---

Output:

```
      Negative     Neutral     Positive
0  0.013780469  0.94494355  0.041276094
1  0.013780469  0.94494355  0.941276094
2  0.513780469  0.74494355  0.041276094
3  0.813780469  0.14494355  0.541276094
```